# Which Data Source

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an xl spreadsheet that I'd like to scrap. I'll replace it with a simple windows form application built with c#.

The spreadsheet has a table with just two columns:

- Date
- Staff Member

So a sample of the table might look like:

- 01-Jan    Jason
- 02-Jan
- 03-Jan    Mike

As you can see it's very simple. I use Sqlserver everyday but it would seem like overkill to put this table into a db on Sqlserver. What datasouce should I use for the windows form - a text file?

note: not sure if it influences my choice of datasouce but I'm thinking of using a calender tool and maybe a datagridview in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not overhead to use sql server at all, if you wish to ditch the file/spreadsheet.
Also using sql-server will be a consistent method of data storage if that is what you currently use for other apps.

It really should take very little time to do.
Also assuming your sql setup does automatic backups etc, then it will ensure you don't lose the information. Hands down make use of sql server if you have access to it.

Answer (score 2):

Seems so simple that you can use a simple text file(key-value), but if you want to expand the capability of the program in the future maybe it is better to put the table in a [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) database, that is a lightweight embedded database and should fit well with your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

If you are used to using SQL Server everyday, the closest thing to that is [SQL Server Compact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff687142), as it is very similar to SQL Server but designed instead to be used as a lightweight, standalone option.  It interfaces with Visual Studio and you should feel right at home with it.